# Using sed to insert some text in a file

Tags: linux, sed

I'm trying to use SED to make some changes to a CUPS configuration file.

What I want to do is find the following text:

```
# Restrict access to the server...
<Location />
  Order allow, deny
```

and append this to it:

```
  Allow from all
```

I've tried `sed '/# Restrict access to the server...\n<Location />\n  Order allow, deny\n/ a\   Allow from all' etc/cups/cupsd.conf` but I don't know how to escape the >, and prepending a backslash to it does not work.

Comment: In my opinion it is always best to modify configuration files manually to be sure that the shanges that are made are those that you expect to be made.

Comment: This is for an initial setup script for convenience.

Comment: `sed` reads one line at a time, you cannot make a multi-line regex match directly. The workarounds involve reading enough lines into the hold space, or building what amounts to a simple state machine (if you see the first line of the pattern, move to the state where you are looking for the second, etc).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work for you:

```
sed 'N;/<Location \/>\n *Order allow, deny/s//&\n  Allow from all/;P;D' file
```

or alternatively

```
sed $'N;/<Location \\/>\\n *Order allow, deny/a\\\nAllow from all\nP;D;' file
```

#### Example

```
$ sed 'N;/<Location \/>\n *Order allow, deny/s//&\n  Allow from all/;P;D' cups.in
# other stuff here
# Restrict access to the server...
<Location />
  Order allow, deny
  Allow from all
</Location>
stuff

$ sed $'N;/<Location \\/>\\n *Order allow, deny/a\\\n  Allow from all\nP;D;' cups.in
# other stuff here
# Restrict access to the server...
<Location />
  Allow from all
  Order allow, deny
</Location>
stuff
```

Note that the order of where the `Allow from all` is added is different, although I don't believe this makes a bit of difference functionality wise.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
sed '/# Restrict access to the server/{$!N;$!N;s/<Location \/>\n  Order allow, deny$/&\n  Allow from all/}' file
```

or this:

```
sed ':a;$!{N;ba};s/# Restrict access to the server[^\n]*\n<Location \/>\n  Order allow, deny[^\n]*/&\n  Allow from all/' file
```

or most probably this (GNU awk?):

```
sed '/# Restrict access to the server/,+3s/Order allow, deny/&\n  Allow from all/' file
```